# Which method in EF5 is in charge of creating database

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, ef-database-first

I have a couple of questions:

1. In EF5 code first API which method is in charge of checks if database exits, and if it's not the case which method creates DataBase?
2. if i use EF code first i my DAL project and i want EF to generate other database for testing purpose can i do this by using ef? I've already changed initial catalog in connection string to check if it creates other database but it does not and threw exception
3. By using ef Code-First or DataBase-First, we finally have DbContext class, EF5 how knows we used which method for it's internal actions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Api for check if exists `Context.Database.Exists();`
and `Context.Database.CreateIfNotExits();`

As soon as you access EF Context it starts doing things.
There is default behavior you can manipulate things.

A context can be Open again different DB Instances yes.
You can even use it to create different DBs on SAME Server.
Careful use of the constructor and corresponsing API.CONFIG setting is required.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="YouCanHaveManyofTheese"
     connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DIFFERENT DBNAME ;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Also
Check out `Database.SetInitializer();`

Ef Knows if it created the DB, or migrated the DB.  The actions are recorded here.
**[dbo].[__MigrationHistory]**

Comment: when i change initial catalog inorder to force ef to generate DB, I've got Login faild for user 'xxx' meaning that database does not exist on the sever